# Generate list of numbers in specific format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I need to generate a list of numbers in a specific format. The format is

```
mylist = [00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15]
#Numbers between 0-9 are preceded by a zero.
```

I know how to generate a normal list of numbers using `range`

```
>>> for i in range(0,16):
...     print i
```

So, is there any built-in way in python to generate a list of numbers in the specified format.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Python [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) allows you to specify a precision:

> Precision (optional), given as a '.' (dot) followed by the precision.

In this case, you can use it with a value of 2 to get what you want:

```
>>> ["%.2d" % i for i in range(16)]
['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12',
 '13', '14', '15']
```

You could also use the zfill function:

```
>>> str(3).zfill(2)
'03'
```

or the string format function:

```
>>> "{0:02d}".format(3)
'03'
```

Comment: @jterrace: you may want to add the equivalent str.format example.

Comment: `"%02d" % i` works too. The advantage of `map("{:02d}".format, range(16))` that it fails on non-integers.

Answer (score 1):

One liner in Python 3.x

```
[f'{i:>02}' for i in range(1, 16)]
```

Output:

```
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
```

Answer (score -1):

in oracle write this query to generate 01 02 03 series

```
select lpad(rownum+1, decode(length(rownum),1,2, length(rownum)),0) from employees
```

Comment: The post clearly states that this is a Python question